# Set View background colors in Interface Builder for MAC OSX App

Tags: macos, interface-builder

I can't figure out how to set background colors in Interface Builder. When the NSView is selected, I can't find any background color menu in inspector attributes. View effects inspector has background filters which are very unfamiliar to me and I failed to get a View background color.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score -5):

You can find it in the Attributes Inspector under View where the Background will be set to Default (white)

Comment: The attributes inspector shows only Focus Ring (default) and Drawing with 3 check boxes : Hidden, Autoresizes Subviews and Can Draw Concurrently. Nothing else.

Comment: I am developping a MAC OSX App